# Stream downloadable files on client side using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, blob

I have this idea of integrating a video player in my website that can stream files that are download only by default , so far I have researched that concluded to a question , that `Can I create a blob object on client side and stream it ?`

```
<video id="player" src="THE_BLOB_OBJECT">

<script>
function blob_create(){
    passedUrl = 'PASSED FROM BACKEND'
    function blob_obj(url){
        // MAGIC CODE TO CREATE A BLOB
        return link
    }
    createdObj = blob_obj(passedUrl)
    document.getElementById('player').src = createdObj
}
</script>
```

I don't know if the above is possible as I have a very little understanding of blob, any alternates to stream a download file will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL(param)` to convert the passed url to blob Object.

Example:

```
function blob_obj(url){
    return URL.createObjectURL(url);
}
```